# Godot: get global position not getting correct position

Tags: godot

I am trying to make a sort of movement map where all the points are connected by lines. But the points next to each other are the only ones being connected, which is what I am trying to do. However, whenever I try to draw a line between the two points, the lines are there but they go in a very different direction than where I want. I have been using get_global_position to get the position of the start and end of the line. Here is my code for the scene:

```
extends Area2D

var point_a = self.get_global_position()
var point_b = 0

var draw_line = false

func _process(delta):
    var overlapping_areas = get_overlapping_areas()
    
    for area in overlapping_areas:
        if area.is_in_group("Location"):
            point_b = area.get_global_position()
            
            draw_line = true
            
            update()
    
func _draw():
    if draw_line:
        draw_line(point_a, point_b, Color(1, 1, 1, 1), 2)
        
        draw_line = false
```

I am new to Godot and coding so there may be something I am just missing.

Comment: I'm not sure, but the first thing that comes to mind is that drawing may be happening in the node's local space rather than global space.  Try `draw_line(to_local(point_a), to_local(point_b), Color(1, 1, 1, 1), 2)`.

Comment: I tried this and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: @0x5453 Yes, that is correct, you might post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `_draw` function draws in the Node's local space, not in global space.  Therefore one valid solution would be:

```
func _draw():
    if draw_line:
        draw_line(to_local(point_a), to_local(point_b), Color(1, 1, 1, 1), 2)
        
        draw_line = false
```